# Fastest way to index huge data in elastic

Tags: elasticsearch

I am asked to index more than 3*10^12 documents in to elastic cluster, the cluster has 50 nodes with 40 cores, and 128G of memory.
I was able to do it with _bulk in python language (multi thread) but I could not reach more than 50,000 records per second for one node.

So I want to know:

1. What is the fastest way to index data?
2. As I know, I can index data to each data node, does it grow linear? I mean I can have 50,000 records for each node?

Comment: Disable the replicas , set it to 0 and make replacs after ingestion is complete. Also see the elastic documentation for indexing speed optimization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your question:

1. Balance your resources. Both Elasticsearch and Your Application will need to try to run at 60-80% of server utilization in order to achieve the best performance. You can achieve this utilization from Application side by using Multiple Processing in python or Unix `xargs` + Elasticsearch `_bulk` API.
2. Elasticsearch performance grows almost linearly with 99%, as my experience. If you have a correct design of your cluster / index-shards settings. `50,000 records/second` for each node is possible.

Here are some useful links that would help:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-performance.html
- https://qbox.io/support/article/choosing-a-size-for-nodes
- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/modules-threadpool.html (for monitoring your cluster during work loads)

It's recommended to do performance testing and then monitor your clusters + application servers closely during workloads. (I used unix htop + newrelic combined :D).

Comment: I used parallel_bulk from python, it seems to be better.

Comment: Absolutely, in such case we can take advantage of the elasticsearch module: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py